# Insert DateTimes of format (yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss +TT:TT) into SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, date, datetime, timezone

I am attempting to build parameters to insert date-times into a database as in:

```
InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TIME1", DateTime.Parse(fubardata[12]));
```

Where fubardata[12] contains "2015-07-22 13:41:53 +00:00" and is a list of strings

I get when I execute the query:

**Conversion Failed when converting date and/or time from character string.** 
The target column is of type Datetimeoffset(7)

**NOTE: The below does not apply** *the Database* isn't doing the formatting, .net is in my case.
[As in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx this string format does not seem to be a supported type its also mentioned it is not supported by various posts on stack overflow.]

I'm hard pressed to find the right cast, or how need to present a Datetime class so SQL parameters accept it. I've seen datetime database data presented to me in this format on several occasions. I'm sure there is a way.

UPDATE: Casting as DateTimeOffset.Parse(fubardata[12]) still throws same exception when used in the paramter set syntax `InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TIME1", DateTimeOffset.Parse(fubardata[12]));`

UPDATE (SOLUTION): 
I've written a small program on a test database that only contains an ID column and the column theTime DateTimeOffset(7) to test out writing these values to a database.
in general, I have found the best way to write times to a database if they come to you in a non-standard string format is:

```
InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@[your param]",SqlDbType.DateTimeOffset).Value = "[date as a string]";
```

FOLLOWS is the code I used to test it. I learned SQL can't handle a daytimeoffset / datetime created from a string of format "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss +-TT:TT" when addwithvalue is used. An important note is that if you table is using DateTimeOffsets, you should turn your datetimes to that DateTimeOffset type before inserting. As a side note I find it awkward that

```
InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[your param]", DateTime.Now)
```

-Causes no problems which people use all the time.

```
    private static void Main()
    {

        SqlConnection DataBaseWriterConnection;
        SqlCommand DataBaseWriterCommand;
        string SqlQueryString;
        List<List<string>> theData = new List<List<string>>();
        List<string> theDataRow1 = new List<string>();
        theDataRow1.Add("2015-07-22 13:41:00 +00:00");
        List<string> theDataRow2 = new List<string>();
        theDataRow2.Add("2015-07-22 13:42:00 +00:00");
        List<string> theDataRow3 = new List<string>();
        theDataRow3.Add("2015-07-22 13:43:00 +00:00");
        theData.Add(theDataRow1);
        theData.Add(theDataRow2);
        theData.Add(theDataRow3);

        DataBaseWriterConnection = new SqlConnection("Server = localhost; database = CA_TakacsTesting; connection timeout=30; Trusted_Connection = Yes");
        try
        {
            DataBaseWriterConnection.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error connecting. Reason:\n" + ex.Message );
        }
        foreach (List<string> aDataRow in theData)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlQueryString = "INSERT INTO DateTimeTesting (theTime) VALUES(@theDateTimeOffset)";


                SqlCommand InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(SqlQueryString, DataBaseWriterConnection);

                InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@theDateTimeOffset", SqlDbType.DateTimeOffset).Value = aDataRow[0];
                InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.WriteLine("No Problems Caused");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot Write for reason:\n" + ex.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }
        DataBaseWriterConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

The resulting database output is:

```
ID  theTime
1   2015-07-22 13:41:00.0000000 +00:00
2   2015-07-22 13:41:00.0000000 +00:00
3   2015-07-22 13:42:00.0000000 +00:00
```

Which is what we want.

Comment: Why are you parsing to a `DateTime` instead of `DateTimeOffset`? Note that the string handling is entirely in .NET code in your example - SQL Server isn't parsing the original string at all.

Comment: I have time represented as a string that I need to pass into a table. I might  need to do DateTimeOffset.Parse() for that string.

Comment: But you're already parsing it in your .NET code - which is good. But you're parsing it to the wrong type - your field type is `DateTimeOffset`, so you should parse it to the .NET `System.DateTimeOffset` type... and I'd suggest using `DateTimeOffset.ParseExact`, and specifying the format (and invariant culture)

Comment: Right, I'm likely missing my culture here hence the need for parse exact as "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss TT:TT" isn't explicitly supported as I've seen on the MSDN Transact SQL page. I need to parse exact the the ISO culture. Trying this next

Comment: Again, ignore the MSDN Transact SQL page, because that's irrelevant - *you're not asking SQL Server to parse your string*. You're doing it in your .NET code and passing the value as a `DateTime` (which should be `DateTimeOffset`)

Comment: I also suspect that given the error you're seeing, you may not actually be getting the problem from the code you're showing us - maybe it's another field? I suggest you narrow this down by creating a dummy database *just* for solving this problem. Create a table with just one field, of type DateTimeOffset, and then update your post with a *complete* example trying to update that. I'd also suggest using `...Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.DateTimeOffset).Value = ...` rather than using `AddWithValue`, but that's a different matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see several bad things here:

1. Date values in Sql Server (including DateTime, DateTime2, DateTimeOffset, etc) do **not** use that format. They are stored in a binary format that is not human-readable. You only see them in that format as convenience provided by the debugger and query tool, or when actually put a date value in raw SQL (and parameters don't create raw SQL, so you only rarely need this).
2. [Don't use AddWithValue()](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)
3. At no point should you ever need to convert DateTimeOffset values to strings.
4. Parsing a field from a DataRow object implies you have a query that should have been written using a JOIN or INSERT + SELECT in a single statement. Build the SQL right, and there's no need to ever have this data at the C# level at all.

You can fix points 1-3 as show below. We need to know more context to help you with point 4.

```
InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@TIME1", SqlDbType.DateTimeOffset).Value = DataRow[12];
```

Comment: 4. This data is from a list<list<string>> produced from classes generated by processing a large dataset; meant to represent a flat file. I'm using the foreach iterator to push rows of the internal string into the database. 
DataRow[x] is grabbing an index from a list of strings then.  I didn't realize DataRow was a keyword for some class. I had just changed its name form my program to something generic for here.